# Need gcc/g++ working on SCO6

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gnu, sco-unix

Has anyone found a way to get gcc to build/install on SCO6?  With 2.95 and 4.3 I get to the point where it needs to use (2.95) or find (4.3) the assembler and that's where it fails.

If anyone has figured this out I would appreciate the info!

Thanks

Comment: People still use SCO anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install GNU binutils first.  It contains the assembler.

Comment: I saw that in the INSTALL file but for some reason it didn't sink in.  I'll give it a try.  Thanks!

Comment: Not surprisingly I'm having trouble getting binutils to build as well.

After './configure --host=i386-pc-sco' then 'make' it fails to build bfd with: UX:acomp: ERROR: "trad-core.c", line 43: incomplete struct/union/enum user: u

Any ideas?

Comment: Zdenik: ask a new StackOverflow question for this.

Answer (score 1):

You might find this on the SCO Skunkware CD:

http://www.sco.com/skunkware/